# How install and configure manually php and apache?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, configuration

Installed PHP like this:

`wget http://in1.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.28.tar.bz2
tar -xvf php-5.3.28.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.28
./configure
make
make install`

Installed Apache2 like this:

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

So, how do I now link Apache to PHP?

PS - I know I can install PHP as a module which will be 100x easier, but I want to know how to link exactly these two in this way.

Thanks.

Comment: there is some reason to not use sudo apt-get install php5?

Comment: Yes, because it will install newest PHP version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your httpd.conf to load the PHP module. The path on the right hand side of the LoadModule statement must point to the path of the PHP module on your system. The make install from above may have already added this for you, but be sure to check.

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

Tell Apache to parse certain extensions as PHP. For example, let's have Apache parse .php files as PHP. Instead of only using the Apache AddType directive, we want to avoid potentially dangerous uploads and created files such as exploit.php.jpg from being executed as PHP. Using this example, you could have any extension(s) parse as PHP by simply adding them. We'll add .php to demonstrate.

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Or, if we wanted to allow .php, .php2, .php3, .php4, .php5, .php6, and .phtml files to be executed as PHP, but nothing else, we'd use this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

And to allow .phps files to be handled by the php source filter, and displayed as syntax-highlighted source code, use this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
```

And restart Apache

```
service httpd restart
```

You can read how do that in the php documentation

> http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php#92797

Comment: The problem with this manual is that I need to install apache same way I installed PHP... And while there are no other options, I will try it.

Comment: Nop, doesn't work. Followed every step. Somehow php isn't parsed. It just opens php page and outputs everything as a text.. Grrr... This is driving me nuts :/

Comment: when this happens apache don't load php as module

Comment: @user3722573 I edit de answer, you can read some solution in this link http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php#92797

Comment: That comment ( http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php#92797 ) saved my day. Thanks.